# I'm getting a "mul object is not callable"-error

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy as sp
def taylorCoefficient(f, a, n):
    x = sp.symbols("x")
    coefficient = []
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        afgeleide = sp.diff(f(x), x, n=n)
        def f(x0): return afgeleide.subs(x, x0)
        coefficient += f(a) / sp.factorial(n)
    return coefficient


x = sp.symbols("x")
taylorCoefficient(x ** 2 * sp.sin(x / 2), 0, 3)
```

I'm getting a mul object is not callable, but why? (On line afgeleide=...)

Comment: traceback please

Comment: Because `f` is a `Mul` object which is not callable. Did you expect it to be? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the last line of your script to `taylorCoefficient( lambda x: x**2*sp.sin(x/2), 0, 3)`.